# Visual Studio 2010 - Debug Output

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why when I change build to debug x86 rather than "Any CPU", do all the calls to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print()` get skipped? I'm using a 64bit machine. Exception output still shows.

Comment: The platform target has nothing to do with the Debug vs Release configuration selection.

Answer (score 2):

You probably changed to a 'Release' build too, and hence DEBUG is not defined.

Comment: Thats what I thought.. I have it set to debug mode. It is only skipped on x86, x64 and Any CPU they do not get skipped?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are only skipped when you compile in Release mode.

Comment: Thats what I thought.. I have it set to debug mode. It is only skipped on x86, x64 and Any CPU they do not get skipped?

Comment: The methods have a Conditional attribute on them which are evaluated by the C#,VB.NET compilers to include this method call if the DEBUG conditional compilation constant is set during build. You can check easily if the call is included by looking at your compiled binary with Reflector, Ildasm,.... If the call is missing you have got a release build from somewhere. Check the time stamps of your binary if you are actually executing the one you think you did build.